# reading a file one character at a time with spaces

Tags: c, file, line-breaks, spaces, fgetc

I'm trying to convert the case from a file and write into another. The file I'm trying to convert has spaces and a few lines. The converted form is written with no spaces and no line breaks. Does anyone know how I can alter my code, so that it includes the spaces and line breaks from the original file?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
FILE *fp1, *fp2;
fp1 = fopen("exercise2.txt", "r");
fp2 = fopen("exercise2_converted.txt", "w");

int singleline;

if (fp1 == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening fp1!\n");
    return 0;
}
if (fp2 == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening fp2!\n");
    fclose(fp1);
    return 0;
}

do
{
    singleline = fgetc(fp1);
    if (islower(singleline))
    {
        singleline = toupper(singleline);
        fputc(singleline, fp2);
    }
    else if (isupper(singleline))
    {
        singleline = tolower(singleline);
        fputc(singleline, fp2);
    }
} while (singleline != EOF);


fclose(fp1);
fclose(fp2);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to consider the case where the char is something else than a letter (hint: use `isalpha`). Other hint:  you can solve your problem by adding 2 lines to your code (~30 characters in all)

Comment: Actually there is an even simpler solution that the one I suggested in my first comment: move line and delete one other line.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks! Now does it but puts 'ÿ' at the end from nowhere. Any idea as to why?

Comment: The `ÿ` is because you output the EOF. Shoul'd be too hard to figure out what to do.

Comment: @Jabberwocky What do you mean exactly? And how do i stop that?

Comment: @Jabberwocky would it be like if its = EOF then it puts nothing?

Comment: The `EOF` is a special value that means you've read past the end of the file. You should not output that value.

Comment: make it `while( (singleline = fgetc( fp1 )) != EOF )  { ... }` instead of `do { ... } while( .. );`

Comment: @OllieParsons _"if its = EOF then it puts nothing"_: more or less. If `singleline` is `EOF` then you shouldn't `fputc` it to the output.

Comment: @Jabberwocky isn't that what the "while (singleline != EOF)" part should prevent?

Comment: @OllieParsons yes, but the test happens too late, the fputc with EOF has already been done then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall beginner's solution:

```
...
do
{
    singleline = fgetc(fp1);
    if (singleline == EOF)
      break;        // end of file => game over quit loop immediately

    // convert char if neessary
    if (islower(singleline))
    {
        singleline = toupper(singleline);
    }
    else if (isupper(singleline))
    {
        singleline = tolower(singleline);
    }

    // output the char
    fputc(singleline, fp2);
} while (1);
...
```

There are shorter solutions, but these are harder to read and to understand for beginners.

Comment: Why this inconsistency in the using of braces? :)

Comment: @CacahueteFrito no special reason